# gh-pages subdirectory files aren't shown up

Tags: github-pages

I have following github page displaying some HTML already: http://json-schema-faker.github.io/json-schema-faker/

this is the source repo (`gh-pages` branch): https://github.com/json-schema-faker/json-schema-faker/tree/gh-pages

Although top-level directory files work perfectly fine:

- http://json-schema-faker.github.io/json-schema-faker/index.html - https://github.com/json-schema-faker/json-schema-faker/blob/gh-pages/index.html
- http://json-schema-faker.github.io/json-schema-faker/globals.html - https://github.com/json-schema-faker/json-schema-faker/blob/gh-pages/globals.html

the lower-level directories files don't work at all, e.g.

- http://json-schema-faker.github.io/json-schema-faker/modules/_class_container_.html -> https://github.com/json-schema-faker/json-schema-faker/blob/gh-pages/classes/_class_container_.container.html

The files are there, uploaded in the repo in `gh-pages` branch. What is wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Github pages is using [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) as default site generator.

Default behavior for jekyll is to ignore folders and files with a name that begins with an underscore (except if you configure jekyll not to ignore them. [See include key in documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/)).

**Fastest resolution** : instruct gh-pages not to use jekyll to process and publish your pages, but just copy all your files on the web server.

To do so, just create an empty **.nojekyll** file at the root of your **gh-pages** branch. Push. And everything is OK.

Comment: great answer :)